# Getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error

Tags: oracle, ora-00979

I keep getting an error when I am trying to execute this code on Oracle

```
SELECT id,
       Max(id),
       artist AS"Artist"
FROM   d_songs
WHERE  duration IN( '3 min', '6 min', '10 min' )
HAVING id < 50
GROUP  BY id;
```

What am I doing wrong? It is saying that this is not a group by expression.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression is the error its giving me

Comment: This is a staggeringly trivial syntax error.  Next time you get such a problem please search for the ORA- code.  Only ask a new question if none of the hundreds of hits you'll get solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

After you're edit, see this from the documentation:

> You attempted to execute a SELECT statement which contained a GROUP BY function such as MIN, MAX, SUM or COUNT.
>   You attempted to execute an expression within the SELECT list which is not in the GROUP BY clause.

Put `Group By` before `Having`, and also include all fields (not the max) in the Group By Clause

```
SELECT id, max(id), artist as "Artist"
From d_songs
Where duration in('3 min', '6 min', '10 min')
where id < 50
Group by id, artist
```

You can view [the docs](http://psoug.org/reference/group_by.html) for more information

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that too but it is still giving me the same error :(

Comment: @coryharms you need to include all fields in the group by (not including the max)

Comment: Thank you! that was what I was doing wrong. Thanks again. I would mark as answer but I need 6 reputation lol.

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation I guess... :(

Comment: Why would the HAVING clause contain "id < 50"? Can you move that to the WHERE clause please?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Sorry, I was just c+p the OP's code - completely missed that.

Comment: Ahem .. it'd be before the group by clause ;)

Comment: -_- * I need to just quite while I'm ahead!